# How can I print a rectangle/square using asterisk with the size dependent on user input?

Tags: java

For example, if the user types in 6 for length and 9 for width, the program should print a rectangle of that size. I know I'd need to use a for-loop, but how would I get it to work so that I can print a complete rectangle?

The below I have so far won't work, and for some reason keeps printing '*' until I press ctrl-c.

```
public static void sum()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter height");
    int height = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter width");
    int width = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i<= height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<=width; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

}

Comment: @navysoul here's the algorithm: You need 2 for loops, one nested within the other. Outer for loop would iterate through the height, and inner for loop iterates through the width. The inner for loop would `System.out.print()` an asterisk every iteration, thus taking care of the rows. The outer for loop would print a new line at the end of the iteration.

Comment: @Churro - I'm still not getting it, it keeps printing '*' until I press ctrl-c

Comment: @UnholySheep The above in my original post, I still can't figure it out...

Comment: You need to learn the difference between `print` and `println` and when to use which one (which the answers already do for you)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int height;
int width;
System.out.print("Enter height: ");
height = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter width: ");
width = sc.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for(int j = 0; i < width; j++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A single for loop could only ever produce a list of asterisks in a single direction, like this: ******

To print out a rectangle, you'd need to use two nested for loops. The following method will complete the action you require:

```
public static void printRectangle(int width, int height) {
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        String row = "";
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            row += "*";
        }
        System.out.println(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only print out the width and not the height itself

Comment: How so? I've tried it and it definitely prints out the correctly sized rectangle?

Comment: Oh okay, I was using the arguments incorrectly. What does row += "*" do?

Comment: The `+=` operator in Java (when applied to Strings) appends the second string to the first and stores it in the first variable.. For example, if you have `String hello = "hello ";` and perform the operation `hello += "world";`, the value of `hello` then becomes "hello world" :)